# Proving an interpolation inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality, reference-request, normed-spaces

I'm going through a paper at the moment. The author used an inequality there without source or proof though, and I'm not able to see the proof myself. It is called 'interpolation inequality', but researches on Google didn't take me closer to a solution. We have a $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $\Vert f\Vert_{L^2(M)}:=\left(\int_M |f|^2\right)^{1/2}$, where $M=[0,N]\times[0,1]\in\mathbb{R}^2$, and $C>0$ is any constant independent of $f$. Furthermore, $Df=(\partial_x f,\partial_y f)$ is the derivative of $f$ and $D^2f$ is the matrix ${\partial_{xx} f~~~\partial_{xy} f \choose \partial_{yx} f~~~\partial_{yy} f}$. Then the ineqality is
$$ \Vert Df\Vert_{L^2(M)}^2 \leq C\cdot\left(\Vert f \Vert_{L^2(M)}\cdot\Vert D^2 f\Vert_{L^2(M)}+\Vert f\Vert_{L^2(M)}^2 \right).$$
$~\\$
If $f$ would be a function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, I thought that partial integration combined with the Cauchy Schwarz inequality looks quite similar. However, I have no clue about where the last summand on the right hand side might come from.

Does anyone have a suggestion about how to prove this inequality? Maybe there is a theorem or something like that, stating anything similar?

I'm looking forward to your answers!
Best,
garador

Comment: What is $Df$ and $D^2f$? If $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ then I might guess that $Df$ is the derivative of $f$.

Comment: You're right, $Df$ is the derivative $(\partial_x f, \partial_y f)$ and $D^2f$ is the Jacobian matrix. But as I wrote above, $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. The one-dimensional case was just an approach of mine to get behind the structure of the inequality.

Comment: Great! Please put this information in the question text.

Comment: just did so... when reading a lot about those expressions, it is hard to guess which notation is clear and which isn't ;) (I meant the Jacobian matrix squared by the way... I'm not sure about the right word for that)

Comment: You might also reference the paper you are reading for context.